# Add ffmpeg metadata to .mp4 that will be visible in Windows Explorer

Tags: ffmpeg, video, windows-explorer, metadata

I'm starting to convert my large and scattered video library to HEVC, using ffmpeg.

I'd like to add a metadata tag that can be displayed as a column in Windows Explorer, so I can keep track of which vides have been converted. For example setting 'Encoded by' to 'hevc' would be ideal.

I'm finding many of the properties available in Explorer don't seem to be recognised by ffmpeg, and do not get put into the output video. Even when I use one that does seem to correspond, like 'copyright', it is not displayed by Explorer even though I can see it in the ffprobe output.

Any suggestions on something workable here?

Comment: I can't help with what metadata that ffmpeg can write, but [this exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6591.msg32875#msg32875) lists the various tags Windows will read to fill out the properties.  MP4s are halfway down the post.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll try using exiftool to add the metadata, since I'm using Powershell scripts to do the recoding anyway.